# What is AppWorkspace in registry?

Tags: windows, themes, registry

In the windows 8 registry key : *HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Colors* , what does "AppWorkspace" signify ?

Context: I am changing the default colors through regedit but AppWorkspace doesn't seem to signify anything that I can find.

Comment: That's not the supported way of changing colors. The supported way is `SetSysColors`, and that would lead you to `COLOR_APPWORKSPACE`.

Comment: @raymond kindly elaborate , and what exactly is appworkspace , is it the color of main section of applications like ms office ?? it is definitely not the explorer main window because that is controlled ny the "window" key

Comment: [It's documented on learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getsyscolor)

Answer (score 0):

"The application workspace is the area in a multiple-document view that is not being occupied by documents."
[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.systemcolors.appworkspace?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)